# Inserting a list into MySQL table, id wise

Tags: python, mysql, web-scraping

I am trying to insert a list into 1 single column in a row .How do I make the list go in a column in the same row with the same `ID`? I cannot get the syntax right.
[image]

social_media is a list like this

```
['https://twitter.com/eddylazzarin?ref=cypherhunter', 'https://www.linkedin.com/in/eddy-lazzarin-66059749?ref=cypherhunter', 'https://a16z.com/author/eddy-lazzarin/?ref=cypherhunter']
```

This is my code

```
    sql = cursor.execute(f"SELECT inv_id FROM Investors WHERE name =\'{name}\'")
    pid = cursor.fetchone()
    pidf = str(pid)[1:2]
    pidff = int(pidf)

        try:
            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO team_members(inv_id,mem_name,picture,experience) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s)", (pidff, port_name, headshot, work_ex,))
            list_str = '|'.join(str(item) for item in so_links)
            cursor.execute(f"UPDATE team_members WHERE mem_name=\'{port_name}\' SET social_media ('{list_str}')")
            raise e
```

`inv_id` is the `FOREIGN_KEY`.

However I cannot get the right syntax
Error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near 'WHERE mem_name='Eddy Lazzarin' SET social_media
> ('https://twitter.com/eddylazzar' at line 1

Comment: Don't call `.format()` on SQL queries; use the `cursor.execute("...", (a, b, c))` syntax, which prevents SQL injection.

Comment: You shouldn't try to fit multiple pieces of information into a single field. I can't see the tables you have, but the '|' separation means that your database isn't 1NF (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form).

Comment: @Dennis Just click on it. How can I put a list of items in a single column then. That must be necessary for so many cases.

Comment: use `=` in `SET` SQL query

Comment: Instead of one table like [("pepper", "red|orange|green|yellow"), ("apple", "red|green"), ("banana", "yellow")], have two different tables: [(0, "pepper"), (1, "apple"), (2, "banana")] and [(0, "red"), (0, "orange"), (0, "green"), (0, "yellow"), (1, "red"), (1, "green"), (2, "yellow")]

Comment: See the "Examples" section of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form#Examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missing `=` in `SET` & wrong position of it

```
cursor.execute("UPDATE team_members SET social_media = %s WHERE mem_name=%s",(list_str,port_name))
```

see the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-transaction.html)